# How to send an image alongside other fields to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery function that does the insert of an image with other fields to the database. Currently my  function only inserts the image but does not insert the other form fields. I am using formData object and I don't understand how to append my fields together with the image file so I can pass it to the ajax request body.
Here is what I have tried so far:

// submit function

```js
function Submit_highschool() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#highschool").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#progress").html(
        'Inserting <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');

      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      var firstname_h = $("#firstname_h").val();
      var middlename_h = $("#middlename_h").val();
      formData.append(firstname_h, middlename_h);

      $.ajax({
        url: 'insertFunctions/insertHighSchool.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(returndata) {
          alert(returndata);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.error(xhr);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

// html form

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="highschool">
  <div class="card" id="highschool">
    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="firstname">First name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname_h" placeholder="First name" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="middlename">Middle name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="middlename_h" placeholder="Middle name" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="grade11_h">Grade 11 Transcript (image) *</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="grade11_h" id="grade11_h" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="Submit_highschool();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

The image name is succesfully inserted in the db and the image is uploaded to the required target location,However, the fields - firstname and middlename are not inserted and I don't understand how to append these properties to the formData.

How can I pass these fields to the formData please?

Comment: You **cannot** insert anything into mysql database using ajax jquery. They can only send some info to PHP. While storing in the database is a **completely different business**. You need to make you mind, with which part you need help: sending data from JS to PHP and then remove mysql from the question, OR storing data to mysql, and in this case remove all JS stuff

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing those out. I have rectified that. On which part I need help on is how to pass the other two form properties i.e firstname and middlename in the formData object

Comment: `formdata.set('firstname_h',$("#firstname_h").val());` and `formdata.set('middlename_h',$("#middlename_h").val());`  - the format for `append` is `append(name, value)` rather than `append(value,value)`

Comment: Thanks,does that mean I can use either of the formdata.set or the append, Or after I set the values as you have shown, do I again need to call the append?

Comment: If the form elements had a name rather than simply an ID then they would, by default, be included in the formdata as you have supplied the `form` as the argument to `new FormData` so you would not need to use either `append` or `set`

Comment: Thanks @ProfessorAbronsius, indeed I just added the name to the form elements and it worked without the need to use either set() or append()

Comment: Good stuff - glad to hear you have it sorted now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Professor Abronsius suggested in the comments section I only needed to add the "name" tag to the form elements and remove the append from my function thus, I have edited the function and the form as follows:

```js
// since I have added the name tag to the form elements, there is now 
// no need to use the append() thus, I have commented out the append 
// lines.

function Submit_highschool() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#highschool").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#progress").html(
        'Inserting <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>');

      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      // var firstname_h = $("#firstname_h").val(); // removed this
      // var middlename_h = $("#middlename_h").val(); // removed this
      //formData.append(firstname_h, middlename_h); // removed this

      $.ajax({
        url: 'insertFunctions/insertHighSchool.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(returndata) {
          alert(returndata);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.error(xhr);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
}
```

// added the "name" tag to the form elements

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="highschool">
  <div class="card" id="highschool">
    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="firstname">First name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname_h" id="firstname_h" placeholder="First name" /> // added name="firstname_h"
    </div>

    <div class="col-3">
      <label for="middlename">Middle name *</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middlename_h" id="middlename_h" placeholder="Middle name" /> // added name="middlename_h"
    </div>

    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="grade11_h">Grade 11 Transcript (image) *</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="grade11_h" id="grade11_h" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right" onclick="Submit_highschool();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach for storing the data with image.

1.In PHP API write logic for Upload image to server using move_uploaded_file() & Insert image file name with server path in the MySQL database using PHP.

2.In JS/JQuery, Read all HTML element & create an object & POST it to the API using AJAX Call.

your JS code should be like this. Hope this will help you to fix the issue.

```
  var RegObj = {
          'Field1': $("#Field1").val(),
          'Field2': $("#Field2").val(),
          'logo': $("#company_logo").attr('src'),
         }
  
        console.log(RegObj);
        
        $.ajax({
          url: "API_PATH_HERE",
          type: "POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(RegObj),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          dataType: 'text',
          success: function (result) {         
                 
            //
          },
          error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            
          }
        });
```